# Current date value is null in react-native-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-datepicker

I am using react-native-datepicker and I need to be able to select any date from the current date which is today.

However, the value for the current date is null. I can select the current date but it has no value. 
Only the dates after the current date have values.

See below my code.

```
<DatePicker
                                date={this.state.date}
                                mode="date"
                                placeholder="Select date"
                                format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                                minDate={new Date()}
                                confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                                cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                                isClearable
                                customStyles={{
                                    dateIcon: {
                                        position: 'absolute',
                                        left: 0,
                                        top: 4,
                                        marginLeft: 0
                                    },
                                    dateInput: {
                                        marginLeft: 36,
                                        borderWidth: 0,
                                        right: 0,
                                        color: "grey"
                                    }
                                }}
                                onDateChange={(date) => { this.setState({ date: date }); }}
                            />
```

Comment: date in the state what's his value?

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you pass `minDate={new Date()}`, if you remove it, you will be able to select dates before today.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker#properties):

> `minDate`: Restricts the range of possible date values.

So `minDate={new Date()}` makes it possible to select only dates that are greater than `new Date()` (today).

Comment: Hi, I have removed the minDate, but the value of the current date is still null, is there a way around this.

Answer (score 1):

default state should be a date, not the null or undefined;

```
this.state ={ date: new Date() }
```